# Is there a way to assign registry key access to a specific application?

Tags: c#, security, registry

**Background**

I am currently designing a custom software licensing program that I will be using for some small Windows applications. I do not expect this to be even remotely secure by today's standards. I have already done my research and understand that it is possible to crack/key any program if given enough effort. All of that being said, if it's okay with all of you I'd like to avoid the topic of software licensing. I am really only providing the background for what I am doing because I know that I will be asked at some point. So hopefully I've addressed that, this is an OS/programming-language related question about how to manipulate the Windows registry via a C# application.

**Question**

I would like my program to store the date of installation in the registry. Additionally, I would like for only the program that *stored* the data to be able to manipulate it. Is there Windows/.NET functionality for changing permissions to a registry value this way?

Comment: Permissions are given to a user. If that user is also administrator / can elevate then there is no stopping them from changing / deleting anything your app stored on the machine.

Comment: A common workarund is to encrypt keys&values so they can't be found without watching the registry during installation and values can't be changed in a meaningful way..

Comment: @TaW so if I understand this correctly... What I am describing is not possible?

Comment: Short answer would be no.  Anyone with admin privileges can modify the values in the registry.

Comment: @Hack Would it really be so bad for a feature like this to exist? Or am I missing something?

Comment: From a user's perspective I prefer to not have such powers with applications.

Comment: @Snoop Yes, it would be that bad. Admins should be able to do what they need to do to a system. I'm not even sure how securing something like a registry key to an application would work. How do you envision such a system functioning?

Comment: @Snoop aside from the how, the registry is separate from your application.  If admins didn't have the ability to modify these keys and something goes wrong, i.e. your app doesn't clean up after uninstall then there would be orphaned keys all over the place, which could then cause other issues.

Comment: @Hack Okay, thanks for the advice. I think that for the time being I like TaW's workaround that provides some obscurity.